# Ordering by Sum from a separate controller part 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, partial-views

Ok, so I had [this working just fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816424/how-can-i-order-my-entries-by-sum-from-a-separate-table) before making a few controller additions and the relocation of some code. I feel like I am missing something really simple here but have spent hours trying to figure out what is going on. Here is the situation.

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sites
end
```

and

```
class Sites < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :questions
end
```

I am trying to display my Sites in order of the sum of the `'like'` column in the Sites Table. From my [previous StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816424/how-can-i-order-my-entries-by-sum-from-a-separate-table) I had this working when the partial was being called in the /`views/sites/index.html.erb` file. I then moved the partial to being called in the /`views/questions/show.html.erb file` and it successfully displays the Sites but fails to order them as it did when being called from the Sites view.

I am calling the partial from the /views/questions/show.html.erb file as follows:

```
<%= render :partial => @question.sites %>
```

and here is the SitesController#index code

```
class SitesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @sites = @question.sites.all(:select => "sites.*, SUM(likes.like) as like_total",
             :joins => "LEFT JOIN likes AS likes ON likes.site_id = sites.id",
             :group => "sites.id",
             :order => "like_total DESC")

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @sites }
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah...turns out that I had move the @sites controller code from the SitesController to the QuestionsController Show action. I then had to change my partial in the /views/questions/show.html.erb page from

```
<%= render :partial => @question.sites %>
```

to

```
<%= render :partial => @sites %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be

```
@sites = @question.sites.all(:select => "sites.*, SUM(likes.like) as like_total",
         :joins => "LEFT JOIN likes AS likes ON likes.site_id = sites.id",
         :group => "sites.id",
         :order => "SUM(likes.like) DESC")
```

Comment: When I put that in the sites controller index action it doesn't do anything. Does it need to go somewhere in the questions controller?